# Problem with centering the flutter widget

Tags: flutter

There's a syntax error at "Center(". what could be wrong?

Here's the message i'm receiving: "Creates a widget that centers its child."

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SplashPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      Center(
        child: Text(
          'n',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 90,
            fontFamily: 'Aclonica',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add "body:" before "Center(", because Scaffold doesn't have a positional parameters

Answer (score 1):

The `Scaffold` takes the main widget in a parameter called `body`. So you should pass the `Center` widget in the `body` parameter of the `Scaffold`.

So something like,

```dart
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: Center(
    ...
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class SplashPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Column(
mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.center,
crossAxisAlignment : CrossAxisAlignment.center,
children : [
Text(
          'n',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 90,
            fontFamily: 'Aclonica',
          ),])
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class SplashPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.center,
crossAxisAlignment : CrossAxisAlignment.center,
children : [
Text(
          'n',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 90,
            fontFamily: 'Aclonica',
          ),])
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a widget, it's best to read through it's documentation once. According to the Scaffold's documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html), the content of the `Scaffold` should be placed within the `body` property, which is a positional parameter (means you need to state the param when initializing the `Scaffold`):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SplashPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center( // Just need to add the `body` property here
        child: Text(
          'n',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 90,
            fontFamily: 'Aclonica',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```